Assign struct method to function type
How is it possible to assign a method to a function type? Is there some type of magic where Go keeps track of the receiver? If so, can anyone point me to where this is documented? I have looked, but my lack of time with Go probably means I am using the wrong terminology.
The following code demonstrates the functionality that I do not understand.
// My code
struct MyController {
  ...
}
func (mc MyController) GetMyStuff(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
 ....
}

// My HTTP Server class
mc := MyController{..}

http.HandleFunc("/stuff", mc.GetMyStuff)
http.ListenAndServe(":3000", nil)

Early on I was writing MyController methods to return an http.HandlerFunc and then capturing a reference to MyController in the implementation. However, this now seems redundant and unnecessary. Go pro's what is more idiomatic?
func (mc MyController) GetMyStuff() http.HandlerFunc {
   return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
      // Use mc.{receiver/type} to capture mc reference
   }
}


Why not implementing https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Handler directly for MyController?

This actually didn't even cross my mind. Most of my controller classes have a set of handlers on them. However, this approach would force me to write smaller controller/router classes. Which would probably be cleaner and easier to maintain for class cohesion. Thanks

These sections of the spec describe it:
https://go.dev/ref/spec#Method_expressions
https://go.dev/ref/spec#Method_values
In short: If you create a function variable from a method, that function variable captures the method's receiver. That is:
type X struct{
  Value int
}

func (x X) F() {
  return x.Value
}

Then, you can do:
a:=X{Value:1}
x1:=a.F  // x1 has a reference to a
b:=X{Value:2}
x2:=b.F  // x2 has a reference to b
fmt.Println(x1(),x2()) // Prints 1 2

